# Card.IO camera flash button for iOS

Tags: ios, card.io

I noticed on the card.io website there is a flash button during the scanning process.  How do I activate that?  I looked at the header files and did not see a property for that.

This is for the iOS SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@CLDev, thanks for asking!

Older versions of the card.io SDK for iOS did indeed include that flash button in the interface. But in the current version, we have taken a new approach.

Now, in a low-light situation the flash will automatically come on, and its brightness will be automatically adjusted by the SDK. We have run lots of experiments, and we think that we've arrived at settings that produce the best results for most cards in most lighting situations.

(Some older devices don't support the APIs for adjusting flash brightness. On those older devices, the SDK will instead display the flash button, as in the past.)

Comment: Hi sir, I'm using your card.io sdk for ios. ISit possible to disable the flashlight even if the light is dim/dark? I set FlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff. but still the flash is coming. How should I disable it?

Comment: @NAZIK no, it is not possible to disable the flash in low-light situations. Can you explain why you would want to?